# Salesforce - multiple pre production environments

Tags: deployment, environment

I am pretty new to Salesforce, just learning. My background is custom applications using Java. So I have two questions:

1) How can I have multiple pre-production environments in Salesforce - like dev, QA and UAT?

2) How can I apply the same configuration/code changes I applied in dev to QA and UAT (or how can I promote my changes from dev to QA and UAT)?

Comment: There are some excellent Trailhead modules that cover Salesforce's preprod environments and migration tools. Try [Change Set Development Model](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/declarative-change-set-development), [Package Development Model](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/sfdx_dev_model), [Org Development Model](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/org-development-model), and various other Salesforce DX modules.

Answer (score 2):

This is your staring point [Application Lifecycle and Development Models](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/application-lifecycle-and-development-models) which will help you to understand more about this topic in Salesforce. As for your questions, below are pointers, where you will find more details on the linked documentation for these topics.

> 1) How can I have multiple pre-production environments in Salesforce - like dev, QA and UAT?

In Salesforce you utilize [Sandboxes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=create_test_instance.htm&type=5) or [Scratch Orgs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs.htm) for these purposes. The number of sandboxes/scratch orgs depends on the edition of your Production instance.

> 2) How can I apply the same configuration/code changes I applied in dev to QA and UAT (or how can I promote my changes from dev to QA and UAT)?

You can do this using couple of different ways:

- [Metadata deployments](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/file_based.htm)
- [Change Sets](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=changesets.htm&type=5)
- [Salesforce DX](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/sfdx_dev_model/sfdx_dev_model_release)

---

Comment: On the management of configuration/code changes my recommendation is to use a VCS and only deploy from there to your orgs (obviously bearing in mind the limitations applied by Salesforce to certain org types and the need to use Change Sets at times). The source of truth should be your VCS, not some unversioned org.